# Targeting a certain class in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, slider

I am trying to create a slider from scratch. When you click the element with class `.slide-next` it should check which element has the class `active` and then fade that one out so that the next slider can be shown. But it does not seem to work. The code is shown below:

```
$('.slide-next').click(function(){
    var className = "active";
    if ($('.slide').hasClass('.' + className)) {
        (".slide").fadeOut("slow");
    } else {
    }
});
```

If anyone can help, it would be much appreciated. For your information, I coded the slider to add the `active` class based on the element the user clicks on like shown below and it works fine. I just need to know how to identify when a certain slider has the class `active` so that one can be faded out?

```
$('.slide-welcome').click(function(){
    $( "#slideshow #welcomeSlide").addClass("active").fadeIn("slow");
    $( "#monitorSlide, #manageSlide, #maintainSlide").removeClass("active").fadeOut("slow");
});

$('.slide-monitor').click(function(){
    $( "#slideshow #monitorSlide").addClass("active").fadeIn("slow");
    $( "#welcomeSlide, #manageSlide, #maintainSlide").removeClass("active").fadeOut("slow");
});

$('.slide-manage').click(function(){
    $( "#slideshow #manageSlide").addClass("active").fadeIn("slow");
     $( "#monitorSlide, #welcomeSlide, #maintainSlide").removeClass("active").fadeOut("slow");
});

$('.slide-maintain').click(function(){
    $( "#slideshow #maintainSlide").addClass("active").fadeIn("slow");
    $( "#monitorSlide, #manageSlide, #welcomeSlide").removeClass("active").fadeOut("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[.hasClass()](http://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) expects just the class `className` not `'.' + className`

Just do this. No need for a dot `.`

```
if ($('.slide').hasClass(className)) {
    $(".slide").fadeOut("slow");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that. I have made the ammendment. IT still does not seem to work. Would i help me giving you the full code?

Comment: @user3224482 - try to reproduce your error in jsfiddle.net and give me the link. that would help a lot.

Comment: @user3224482 you're missing the `$` in front of `$(".slide").fadeOut("slow")`.. check for console for errors. looks like you have multiple errors. if you google them, you will find good results. http://jsfiddle.net/r3FHp/3/

Comment: Ok its working but it fades out all of the slides. What do i need to do to make sure it only fades out the slide with the "active" class on it? Do i need to use 'THIS' command anywhere? Thanks

Comment: use `$(".slide.active").fadeOut("slow");` to fade out active slide.